# nested_form links are not working on heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nested-forms

I am using nested_form gem for the first time and I stuck on strange problem it could be because of assets pipeline perhaps. This is my applicatiion.js.coffee file

```
#= require jquery
#= require pace
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
#= require jquery-1.10.2.min.js
#= require jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
#= require bootstrap-select
#= require bootstrap-switch
#= require bootstrap-typeahead
#= require flatui-checkbox
#= require flatui-radio
#= require jquery.tagsinput
#= require jquery.placeholder
#= require underscore
#= require backbone
#= require twitter/bootstrap
#= require bootstrap-switch
#= require flatui-checkbox
#= require share
#= require restaurant
#= require jquery.ui.core.min
#= require jquery.ui.position.min
#= require jquery.ui.tabs.min
#= require jquery.ui.timepicker
#= require jquery.ui.widget.min
#= require jquery.remotipart
#= require deal
#= require dashboard
#= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
#= require flippant.min
#= require bootstrap.min
#= require bootstrap-select
#= require bootstrap.js
#= require bootstrap-editable
#= require bootstrap-switch
#= require flatui-checkbox
#= require flatui-radio.js
#= require flatui-fileinput
#= require holder.js
#= require html5shiv
#= require icon-font-ie7
#= require jquery.placeholder.js
#= require jquery.tagsinput.js
#= require jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
#= require jquery-1.8.3.min.js
#= require jquery-2.0.3.min.js
#= require respond.min
#= require typeahead
#= require vex.combined.min
#= require client
#= require jquery_nested_form
window.Views = {}
window.Routers = {}
```

and these are my models

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :deal_items
  has_many :item_prices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :swap_items
  has_many :required_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_prices, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:price].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :required_options, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:question].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :section
  validates :item_prices, :presence => true
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:small => '50x50#', :large => '100x100#', :medium=>"80x80#"},
              :default_url => '/assets/images/missing_:style.png'
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :title, :description, :photo, :options, :section_id
end

class RequiredOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:choice].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :question, :menu_item_id
end

class ItemPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
  has_many :deal_items
  attr_accessible :size, :price, :menu_item_id
end
```

and my controller is

```
def new
  @section = Section.find(params["section_id"])
  @menu = @section.menu
  @item = @section.menu_items.build
  item_price = @item.item_prices.build
  required_option = @item.required_options.build
  option = required_option.options.build
end
```

view is look like

```
<%= nested_form_for @item, :url=> section_menu_items_create_path(@section, @item), method: :post, class: "js_menu_form", :multipart => true, :role=>"form" do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :item_prices do |price| %>
    <%= price.select :size, options_for_select(["Regular Size", "Small Size","Large Size","Extra Large Size"]),{},:class=>"form-control" %>
    <%= price.text_field :price, :class=>"form-control ", :placeholder=>"Enter price" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an item price", :item_prices %></p>

  <%= f.fields_for :required_options do |r_op| %>
    <%= r_op.text_field :question, :class=>"form-control",  :placeholder=>"Enter a question for this option"  %>
    <%= r_op.fields_for :options do |op| %>
    <%= op.text_field :choice, :class=>"form-control",:size=>5, :placeholder=>"Enter choice" %>
    <%= op.link_to_remove "", :class=>"glyphicon glyphicon-trash", :title=> "remove choice" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However it is working fine on my local machine but on heroku link_to_add and link_to_remove are not working nothing happens when I click on them no new form fields generated or remvoed What I am missing.?

Comment: Certainly not short on jQuery versions, I count 4 separate ones in that list of requires...  Do you have a stack trace to go along with this error?  You say they're "not working", that doesn't help much.

Comment: I have updated my question when I click to add new fields for nested model or to remove them nothing happens on heroku. But every thing is working fine locally I have updated all assets.

Comment: Is the `<a href...>` tag created for the form correct?  Can you use your browser tools to see if any request is being made when you click it?  What does `heroku logs` say when you click it?

Comment: nothing happens in console or network by clicking on these links and heroku logs do not show any thing

Comment: I have the same problem 2 years later. Looks like a Jquery issue, but as you, i have no error showing in any log. Could you find an answer ?